# Chances of generating same String if first 5 chars from a UUID string is removed?

Tags: node.js, express, uuid

If we remove first 5 characters of the `UUID` String which I am generating from here [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), what are the chances of collisions ?

Are there more chances when UUID's will be generated concurrently at the same time ??

Comment: If you remove the first 5 chars, then it won't be an UUID.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Yes I know but I want to know how much chances will be there that those generated strings will repeat? thanks anyways.

Comment: Are you using UUIDv1 or UUIDv3/4/5? They have very different properties.